# how set current wallpaper as my application background image Android?

Tags: android, background, wallpaper

I want to get mobile`s current wallpaper and set that image as the background image of the application. I tried this way but its show a run time exception

```
final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
layout.setBackground(wallpaperDrawable);
```

Comment: Check [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713731/use-phone-wallpaper-as-app-background-theme-wallpaper-like-behaviour)

Answer (score 1):

```
 final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
 final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getFastDrawable();
 getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(wallpaperDrawable);
```

Comment: what if user uses live wallpaper? How to set live wallpaper as app background?